# Spinning the elements of an array clockwise in JS

Tags: javascript

I am supposed to rotate an array of integers clockwise in JS.

Here is my code for it:

```js
function rotateArray(N, NArray)
{
    //write your Logic here:
    for(j=0;j<2;j++){
        var temp=NArray[N-1];
        for(i=0;i<N-1;i++){
            NArray[i+1]=NArray[i];
        }
        NArray[0]=temp;
    }

    return NArray;
}

// INPUT [uncomment & modify if required]
var N = gets();
var NArray = new Array(N);
var temp = gets();
NArray = temp.split(' ').map(function(item) { return parseInt(item, 10);});


// OUTPUT [uncomment & modify if required]
console.log(rotateArray(N, NArray));
```

The code accepts an integer N which is the length of the array. The input is as follows:

```
4
1 2 3 4
```

The correct answer for this case is supposed to be

```
4 1 2 3
```

But my code returns

```
4 1 1 1
```

I cannot find where my code is going wrong. Please help me out.

Comment: That is because I want to rotate the array twice.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after posting. Anyway, the solution is to iterate over the array backwards, so you don't overwrite all elements with the first one. I.e. save the last element for later, then set it to the second to last, then the second to last to the third to last, etc. -- to rotate the array multiple times, it's better to call your function multiple times.

Comment: Thanks a lot I got your point.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is move one item from the end of the array to the beginning. This is very simple to accomplish with `.pop()` (removes an item from the end of an array), then declare a new array with that element as the first:

```js
function rotateArray(N, NArray) {
  const lastItem = NArray.pop();
  return [lastItem, ...NArray];
}
console.log(rotateArray(1, [1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Doing anything else, like using nested loops, will make things more unnecessarily complicated (and buggy) than they need to be.

If you don't want to use spread syntax, you can use `concat` instead, to join the `lastItem` with the `NArray`:

```js
function rotateArray(N, NArray) {
  const lastItem = NArray.pop();
  return [lastItem].concat(NArray);
}
console.log(rotateArray(1, [1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

If you aren't allowed to use `.pop`, then look up the last element of the array by accessing the array's `[length - 1]` property, and take all elements before the last element with `.slice` (which creates a sub portion of the array from two indicies - here, from indicies 0 to the next-to-last element):

```js
function rotateArray(N, NArray) {
  const lastItem = NArray[NArray.length - 1];
  const firstItems = NArray.slice(0, NArray.length - 1);
  return [lastItem].concat(firstItems);
}
console.log(rotateArray(1, [1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function rotate(array,n){
    Math.abs(n)>array.length?n=n%array.length:n;
    if(n<0){
        n=Math.abs(n)
        return array.slice(n,array.length).concat(array.slice(0,n));

    }else{
        return array.slice(n-1,array.length).concat(array.slice(0,n-1));
    }
    
}
    console.log(rotate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],-3));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an explanation of what your code is doing and how it differs from the methods described in the answer which came before yours

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @CertainPerformance is great but there's a simpler way to achieve this. Just combine [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) with [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4];
a?.length && a.unshift(a.pop());
console.log(a);
```

You **need** to check the length first so you don't end up with `[undefined]` if you start with an empty array.